# AS3: Drawing Lines With Touch Screens

Tags: android, ios, actionscript-3, flash, multi-touch

,Hey guy's I am kind of a newbie with AS3 and there touch events, for touch screens. So what I am trying to look to do is draw a line behind where ever the user is dragging his/her finger, then on release clear the line. I am also hoping to do multi-touch so the user can use multiple fingers, not to sure if that's possible with AS3 though. Thanks for the help everyone! Currently working off of this

```
import flash.ui.Multitouch;
import flash.ui.MultitouchInputMode;
import flash.events.TransformGestureEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

var lineContainer:Shape = new Shape();

square_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_PAN, onPan);
square_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ROTATE, onRotate);
square_mc.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_ZOOM, onZoom);
stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drawlines);

square_mc.gotoAndStop(1);

function onPan (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    square_mc.y += e.offsetY;
    square_mc.x += e.offsetX;
    square_mc.gotoAndStop(3);
}

function onRotate (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    square_mc.rotation += e.rotation;
    square_mc.gotoAndStop(2);
}

function onZoom (e:TransformGestureEvent):void{
    square_mc.scaleX *= e.scaleX;
    square_mc.scaleY *= e.scaleY;
    square_mc.gotoAndStop(4);
}

function drawlines(e:MouseEvent):void {
            lineContainer.graphics.clear(); 
            lineContainer.graphics.lineStyle(5, 0x0099FF); 
            lineContainer.graphics.endFill();
}
```

Comment: You need to show some effort. Look at the documentation for touch events and the drawing API and if you run into trouble come back with a specific question.

Comment: Ok I will. Now does mouseDown and mouseUp work with touch screens?

Comment: I believe so. Why don't you get stuck in and try?

Comment: Trying it now just wanted to see what you thought about that before I went through the whole process, because I am not familiar with any touch screen down or anything like that, or if that even exist.

Comment: *updated* With attempt line not showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mouse events do work in touchscreens. Example a left mouse-click becomes a "tap". Best put

`trace ("I am Mouse Click.. working!!")` 

as first line inside that `function drawlines(e:MouseEvent):void` if you get that trace message then the code is working fine.

Also you won't see anything with your code cos even though you got `var lineContainer:Shape = new Shape();` you did not then later add that shape to the display with `addChild (lineContainer);` So Flash knows what you mean but you havent told it to show you what's happening.

Final advice is best make a container Sprite also for the LineContainer. The Sprite has the ability to listen for Mouse events just like the Stage. If you called this Sprite "canvas" then 
 
`canvas.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, drawlines);`

Comment: Thank you for the help it cleared some things up, but my line is still not drawing.

Comment: I've been away from **S.O** for a few days. Are you now able to draw your lines? Your function `drawlines` did setup a line-style (size, colour) but then did not actually draw one (no setup for position or length). Check this tutorial: [AS3 Draw Lines](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3drawvectors/). PS: Whenever Googling an AS3 problem and Republic Of Code shows in those results.. check 'em out. Had good solid info for me when I was beginner

Comment: Yes it did, ended up doing it differently but your way also worked